# Delete all files and directories except the ones in a list

Tags: c#, .net, delete-file

I have two tasks in hand

1. Get 10 latest files from a folder lets say `C:\Temp` and
2. Delete any other folders and files.

I got the first item working by using the below code, thanks for our friends in Stack Overflow.

```
var imgFiles = (from f in directory.GetFiles(fileType,SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                            select f).Take(numberOfFilesToFetch).ToArray();
```

I need some help with point **2.**  Some sample C# code will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to delete the files I propose that you only get the list of the files to deleted, So you can use **Skip** instead of **Take**

Others aproach are calling **GetFiles** again with an **Except** call which is not very efficient if you dont need the list of files to ignore during the delete process

```
var filesToBeDeleted = (from f in Directory.GetFiles(fileType,SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                            select f).Skip(numberOfFilesToFetch).ToArray();

foreach (var file in filesToBeDeleted)
{
    file.Delete();
}

string [] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\temp");

foreach(string dir in subdirectoryEntries)
{
    Directory.Delete(dir) ;
}
```

I recommend that you add a try,catch for the delete operations

Comment: The above works however it only deletes the files not the folders.

Comment: @Abe I just added the part to delete the folders

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles().Except(imgFiles))
{
    file.Delete();
}
```

Comment: you are calling GetFiles again which is no very efficient. Why not change the original LINQ so that it only has the files to be deleted ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var filesToBeDeleted = directory.GetFiles(fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                .Except(imgFiles).ToArray();
for (int i = filesToBeDeleted.Length; i >= 0; i--)
    filesToBeDeleted[i].Delete();
```

Comment: you are calling GetFiles again which is no very efficient. Why not change the original LINQ so that it only has the files to be deleted ?